# Create custom Play2 Action to retrieve IP address from header

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to figure out a good way of retrieving the ipadress that is stored
in the header for the key **X-FORWARDED-FOR** in the controllers of my app. My initial thought is to use [Actions](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaActions) and [ActionComposition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaActionsComposition)  but I'm not sure how to do this. I guess I
I should in my CustomAction loop through the headers, wrap the request with a case class that takes ipadress as argument, add the ip to that case class and then access the ipadress by request.ipadress in the controller.

Is this a good way and/or how would you implement this in scala?

Comment: I think that's a good way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play can manage that behavior without tricks.

Simply add `trustxforwarded=true` to your application.conf, and get the ip with [`request. remoteAddress`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/9e967d77bd381217ceb85d5fc01a0dbc2ad444d1/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L58).

All the details are explained here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/HTTPServer

Answer (score 0):

I won't say it is a bad way. It actually seems good.

But did you notice there was a `remoteAddress()` method on request headers? If yes, sorry to mention it. If no, it may help you.